# Update hidden value after soft deleting in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http-delete

I have four tables:

- Agroindustria
- Pessoa
- PessoaJuridica
- Endereco

. Here are their Models:

**Agroindustria**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Agroindustria extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "agroindustria";
    protected $primaryKey = "CodAgroindustria";
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public $fillable = ['CodAgroindustria, Porte'];
    public $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    public function pessoa () {
        return $this->setConnection('diana')->hasOne(Pessoa::class, 'CodPessoa', 'CodAgroindustria');
    }

    public function pessoajuridica()
    {
        return $this->setConnection('diana')->hasOne(PessoaJuridica::class, 'CodPessoa', 'CodEndereco');
    }

    public function endereco()
    {
        return $this->setConnection('diana')->hasOne(PessoaJuridica::class, 'CodEndereco', 'CodEndereco');
    }

    public function estado(){
        return $this->setConnection('diana')->hasOne(Estado::class, 'CodEstado', 'estado');
    }

    public function cidade(){
        return $this->setConnection('diana')->hasOne(Cidade::class, 'CodCidade', 'cidade');
    }
}
```

**Pessoa:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Pessoa extends Model
{
    // use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "pessoa";
    protected $primaryKey = "CodPessoa";
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $connection = "diana";

    public $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'EXCLUIDO', 'LastSend'];
    public $fillable = ['email', 'TelRes', 'TelCel'];

    public function endereco()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Endereco', 'CodEndereco', 'CodEndereco');
    }

    public function pessoafisica()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PessoaFisica', 'CodPessoaFisica', 'CodPessoa');
    }

    public function pessoajuridica()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PessoaJuridica', 'CodPessoaJuridica', 'CodPessoa');
    }

}
```

The **PessoaJuridica** and **Endereco** Models are pretty much the same as the **Pessoa** Model.

When I soft delete my **Agroindustria**, the deleted_at column updates successfully, but I'm struggling with updating the **EXCLUIDO** column values from 0 to 1 in my other models.
Here's the delete function I created in my **AgroindustriaController:**

```
public function deletar (Request $request)
{
    try {
        $Agroindustria = Agroindustria::where('CodAgroindustria', $request['CodAgroindustria']);
        $Agroindustria->delete();

        $Pessoa = Pessoa::findOrFail($request['CodPessoa']);
        if ($Agroindustria->delete()) {
            DB::table('Pessoa')->where('CodPessoa', $Pessoa->CodPessoa)
                ->update(array('EXCLUIDO' => 1));
        }

        return response()->json([
            'error' => false,
            'data' => [
                'message' => 'Dados deletados com sucesso',
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => [$e->getMessage()]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: do u want to soft delete child relationship  as well .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes. I want the EXCLUIDO column from the Pessoa, PessoaJuridica and Endereco Model to update from 0 (not deleted) to 1 (deleted) when a registry from the Agroindustria Model is soft deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

second line in try

```
$Agroindustria->delete();
```

write this line like this

```
$dlt = $Agroindustria->delete();
```

after that in your if condition put this variable $dlt like this

```
if ($dlt) {
        DB::table('Pessoa')->where('CodPessoa', $Pessoa->CodPessoa)
            ->update(array('EXCLUIDO' => 1));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for the response Sunil, but unfortunately that didn't work...

Comment: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found"

Comment: import this class in that controller

Comment: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Comment: import DB in AgroindustriaController 
like this 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing:

```
$Agroindustria = Agroindustria::where('CodAgroindustria', $request['CodAgroindustria']);
$dlt = $Agroindustria->delete();

if ($dlt) {
    Pessoa::where('CodPessoa', $request['CodPessoa'])
        ->update(array('EXCLUIDO' => 1));
    PessoaJuridica::where('CodPessoaJuridica', $request['CodPessoaJuridica'])
    ->update(array('EXCLUIDO' => 1));
    Endereco::where('CodEndereco', $request['CodEndereco'])
    ->update(array('EXCLUIDO' => 1));
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers have a look there, the better way to solve that kind of problems, imho